# Create team with powershell

Tags: powershell

Everyone.
I am going to create team with powershell.
I have created .ps1 file and write the content as following.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
New-Team -DisplayName "Tech Reads"
```

But I had got an error like this.

```
New-Team : Error occurred while executing
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Unsupported token. Unable to initialize the authorization context.
InnerError:
  RequestId: a2abece6-8676-4288-b7f2-fa9103423cb7
  DateTimeStamp: 2021-08-12T01:02:40
HttpStatusCode: Request_BadRequest
At D:\git\create-team-powershell\create-team.ps1:2 char:1
+ New-Team -DisplayName "Tech Reads"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Team], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.ErrorHandling.ApiException,Microsoft.TeamsCmdle
   ts.PowerShell.Custom.NewTeam
```

I can 't understand why this happens and hope your kind help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least also include `Connect-AzureAD` and `Connect-AzAccount` at the beginning of the script, and of course provide proper credentials with the right access rights.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).